# Having trouble passing contents of UITextField from one controller to another

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I want to pass whatever string a user inputs into a `UITextField' over to the destination view controller, but when I NSLog the value in the destination, it shows up as null. I'm also getting a warning stating:`incompatible pointer types assigning to UITextField from NSString`. How can I properly make the assignment and send it over?

**Originating view controller**

SearchViewController.m:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    controller.itemSearch = self.itemSearch.text;
}
```

SearchViewController.h:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *itemSearch;
```

**Destination view controller**

UserCategoryChooserViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SearchViewController.h"

@interface UserCategoryChooserViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *itemSearch;
```

UserCategoryChooserViewController.m:

```
NSLog(@"The text is:'%@'", self.itemSearch.text); // results in (null)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above two answer are also correct. But if you want to make the assignment properly then modified textfield variable as NSString variable like that below:

```
 @interface UserCategoryChooserViewController:UIViewController
 @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *itemSearch;
```

After doing this your warning
incompatible pointer types assigning to `UITextField` from `NSString` will get removed

Answer (score 1):

controller.itemSearch is a UITextField *, and you tried to set it to a NSString *, that's what that warning is for. To set text of a UITextField, try this:

```
[controller.itemSearch setText:self.itemSearch.text];
```

There might be other issues, but let's start from here.

Answer (score 1):

Let's go through the error you are seeing. It says that you are assigning an `NSString *` to a `UITextField *`. Unfortunately, you cannot do that. Here, `itemSearch` is the text field.

To make your code run properly, you need to set the `text` property of the `itemSearch` text field. The correct code would be:

```
controller.itemSearch.text = self.itemSearch.text;
```

As a side note, you should really not be meddling so deep into iOS development until you have made a strong foundation, which you have not.